# Authenticating with Last.fm in Jquery - Invalid method signature supplied

Tags: javascript, jquery, api, md5, last.fm

I'm trying to auth a Last.fm session and am struggling to sign a request for a session key correctly.

I keep receiving `Invalid method signature supplied` However when I md5 hash what i believe the query should consist of outside of JS, I get the same signature. I must be including the wrong data in the string I guess, but can't figure out what.

I know there are a few other questions and i've ran through them all to see what's going wrong here, but I swear it looks right to me.

This is the signing algorithm and Ajax call. I've tried to leave enough sample data too.

```
// Set elsewhere but hacked into this example:
var last_fm_data = {
    'last_token':'TOKEN876234876', 
    'user': 'bob',
    'secret': 'SECRET348264386'
};

// Kick it off.
last_fm_call('auth.getSession', {'token': last_fm_data['last_token']});


// Low level API call, purely builds a POSTable object and calls it. 
function last_fm_call(method, data){  
    // param data - dictionary.

    last_fm_data[method] = false; 
    // Somewhere to put the result after callback.

    // Append some static variables
    data['api_key'] = "APIKEY1323454";
    data['format'] = 'json';
    data['method'] = method;
    post_data = last_fm_sign(data);

    $.ajax({
      type: "post",
      url: last_url,
      data: post_data,
      success: function(res){
          last_fm_data[method] = res;
          console.log(res['key'])// Should return session key.
      },
      dataType: 'json'
     });
}

function last_fm_sign(params){
    ss = "";
    st = [];
    so = {};
    Object.keys(params).forEach(function(key){
        st.push(key); // Get list of object keys
    });
    st.sort(); // Alphabetise it 
    st.forEach(function(std){
        ss = ss + std + params[std]; // build string
        so[std] = params[std];  // return object in exact same order JIC
    });    
        // console.log(ss + last_fm_data['secret']);
        // api_keyAPIKEY1323454formatjsonmethodauth.getSessiontokenTOKEN876234876SECRET348264386
    hashed_sec = unescape(encodeURIComponent($.md5(ss + last_fm_data['secret'])));
    so['signature'] = hashed_sec; // Correct when calculated elsewhere.
    return so; // Returns signed POSTable object
}
```

Anything anyone can see that i'm missing here? I'm absolutely stumped why this isn't returning a correctly signed POSTable object in the format requested [here](http://www.last.fm/api/webauth). Thanks for your time.

Edit: can't thank anyone for their time if i don't get any advice! No one had any experience with last.fm?

Comment: Try removing    `data['format'] = 'json';`

Comment: Thanks, i'll try this along with the answer below.

Comment: Cheers, although slightly off - I've edited my own answer below with what I found regarding the format attribute.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So on testing some of the responses, I found the solution. There were 2 issues. 
EDITED see below (
The first was needing to remove

```
data['format'] = 'json';
```

as [George Lee](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2315360/george-lee) pointed out. Thanks George. 
)

The other issue was that I'd named a variable incorrectly so was being POSTed with the wrong name. The line

```
so['signature'] = hashed_sec;
```

should have been

```
so['api_sig'] = hashed_sec;
```

I noticed this in Pankaj's answer but unfortunately the rest of his answer (i.e. including the method) was incorrect. Making these 2 changes resolved the call and signed it correctly.

Thanks for all the suggestions!

EDIT:
After some more playing, i've found that

```
data['format'] = 'json';
```

IS correct, however it DOESN'T get hashed with the signature. 
Adding `data['format'] = 'json';` to the POST object after hashing works, and in this instance will return JSON as opposed to XML - which was the preferred method. Adding after hashing  is not documented anywhere that I can find, so there you go. 
The new working code is as follows, and this shows the 2 lines indicated with `--------------------`

```
// Set elsewhere but hacked into this example:
var last_fm_data = {
    'last_token':'TOKEN876234876', 
    'user': 'bob',
    'secret': 'SECRET348264386'
};

// Kick it off.
last_fm_call('auth.getSession', {'token': last_fm_data['last_token']});


// Low level API call, purely builds a POSTable object and calls it. 
function last_fm_call(method, data){  
    // param data - dictionary.

    last_fm_data[method] = false; 
    // Somewhere to put the result after callback.

    // Append some static variables
    data['api_key'] = "APIKEY1323454";
    data['method'] = method;
    post_data = last_fm_sign(data);
    // THEN ADD THE FORMAT ---------------------------------------
    post_data['format'] = 'json';
    $.ajax({
      type: "post",
      url: last_url,
      data: post_data,
      success: function(res){
          last_fm_data[method] = res;
          console.log(res['key'])// Should return session key.
      },
      dataType: 'json'
     });
}

function last_fm_sign(params){
    ss = "";
    st = [];
    so = {};
    Object.keys(params).forEach(function(key){
        st.push(key); // Get list of object keys
    });
    st.sort(); // Alphabetise it 
    st.forEach(function(std){
        ss = ss + std + params[std]; // build string
        so[std] = params[std];  // return object in exact same order JIC
    });    
        // console.log(ss + last_fm_data['secret']);
        // api_keyAPIKEY1323454formatjsonmethodauth.getSessiontokenTOKEN876234876SECRET348264386
    hashed_sec = unescape(encodeURIComponent($.md5(ss + last_fm_data['secret'])));
    so['api_sig'] = hashed_sec; // RENAMED THIS ----------------------------
    return so; // Returns signed POSTable object
}
```

Comment: Yeah I did see somewhere in the API documentation that it could be returned as JSON but didn't see anywhere on how to do it. Glad you've got it all sorted though!

Answer (score 5):

After investigating your code and other posts related to `last.fm` api call, I found that @george lee in fact is correct. You don't need to provide `format` while generating the `auth_sign`.

Apart from that you need to apply `$.md5()` to `auth_sign` string after applying `encodeURIComponent()` and `unescape()` functions. Like this.

```
hashed_sec = $.md5(unescape(encodeURIComponent(ss + last_fm_data['secret'])));
```

Also while making `ajax` call you need to pass `api_key, token & api_sig` as `data`. But seeing your code, reveals that you are passing `api_key, token, format, method & signature`.

So you need to remove `format, method & signature` from the `data` field of `ajax` call.

Instead you need to pass `api_key, token & api_sig` to the `data` field.

So the final code after commenting the `data['format'] = 'json';` line will look like this.

```
    // Set elsewhere but hacked into this example:
    var last_fm_data = {
        'last_token':'TOKEN876234876', 
        'user': 'bob',
        'secret': 'SECRET348264386'
    };

    // Kick it off.
    last_fm_call('auth.getSession', {'token': last_fm_data['last_token']});


    // Low level API call, purely builds a POSTable object and calls it. 
    function last_fm_call(method, data){  
        // param data - dictionary.
        last_fm_data[method] = false; 
        // Somewhere to put the result after callback.

        // Append some static variables
        data['api_key'] = "APIKEY1323454";
        //data['format'] = 'json';
        data['method'] = method;

        post_data = last_fm_sign(data);

        $.ajax({
          type: "POST",
          url: last_url,
          data: post_data,
          success: function(res){
              last_fm_data[method] = res;
              console.log(res['key'])// Should return session key.
          },
          dataType: 'json'
         });
    }

    function last_fm_sign(params){
        ss = "";
        st = [];
        so = {};
        so['api_key'] = params['api_key'];
        so['token'] = params['token'];
        Object.keys(params).forEach(function(key){
            st.push(key); // Get list of object keys
        });
        st.sort(); // Alphabetise it 
        st.forEach(function(std){
            ss = ss + std + params[std]; // build string
        });
        ss += last_fm_data['secret'];
            // console.log(ss + last_fm_data['secret']);
            // api_keyAPIKEY1323454formatjsonmethodauth.getSessiontokenTOKEN876234876SECRET348264386
        hashed_sec = $.md5(unescape(encodeURIComponent(ss)));
        so['api_sig'] = hashed_sec; // Correct when calculated elsewhere.
        return so; // Returns signed POSTable object
    }
```

[Please refer to this link.](http://www.last.fm/api/authspec)

Comment: Thank You! I'll try this as soon as possible and let you know the outcome. I did try it without the method alone, and that drew an XML response instead of JSON but i'll try it with the other steps and see.

Comment: Still haven't had chance to test this yet unfortunately.

Comment: Thanks for the help, I spotted a mistake in my code thanks to the example here.